# Why /usr/bin/login does not fopen() /etc/shadow or /etc/passwd in OSX

Tags: macos, fopen

I fired up *opensnoop* as `sudo opensnoop -f /etc/shadow` as well as `sudo opensnoop -f /etc/passwd` on my OSX Yosemite installation and then launched `/usr/bin/login`, typed in credentials and got a usual prompt however `opensnoop` never showed access to `passwd` or `shadow`. Why is that?

Comment: apple.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place for this.

Comment: @Barmar I think this is more of UNIX-related question though as concerns mainly `fopen()`

Comment: The reason I suggested that is because I suspect OS X doesn't use `/etc/passwd`, it has its own user database.

Comment: @Barmar in the light of that I agree then

Answer (score 0):

Apple likes to "think different". The location (and access methods) of the password hash data has changed a few times in various versions of OS X. As of 10.9 it moved to [/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/(USERNAME).plist](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703020831/http://www.michaelfairley.co/blog/2014/05/18/how-to-extract-os-x-mavericks-password-hash-for-cracking-with-hashcat/)

Comment: Pointing opensnoop at `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/myuser.plist` didn't show anything at all when logging in using `/usr/bin/login`